# SAS. How to write "OR"

Tags: sampling, sas

How to write "OR" in this example?

DATA a1;
set a;
if var1=1 OR 2;
run;

P.S. va1 is the categorial (with categories: 1, 2, 3)

Comment: You can use :var1=1 or var1=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm assuming this will be migrated to stack overflow, but instead of trying to do `if var1=1 or 2` wouldn't it be better to use `if var1 in (1, 2)`?

...and somebody with enough reputation should probably create an sas tag (and an spss tag while you're at it) unless data scientists only use open source languages like `r` and `python` now...

Comment: <if var1 in (1, 2)>
This is really what I need. THANK YOU! )

Comment: @Ted awesome.  if that solved your problem, click the checkmark to accept this answer so everybody knows you're good to go.  and remember there's a wealth of `r` information over at [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r).